# Alternative to the move command?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

As you know, account commands are deprecated in the future. In the same wallet, how do we carry other address bitcoins in one address ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, even with accounts. Bitcoin is not transferred between addresses when using the `move` command. It does not magically transfer Bitcoin from one address to another when you use `move`. The only way to do that is to make a Bitcoin transaction. All that `move` did was it changed which account an address was associated with. Nothing was actually moved, just a wallet internal database entry was changed.